# How to detect running app from JWrapper bundle and pass commandline arguments to it

Tags: jwrapper

We have recently decided to move our application deployment over to JWrapper and have started dealing with the smaller changes required to implement all the features for our tool. In particular, we have a custom protocol that we handle using the protocol registration in JWrapper. We do this in a separate (non-user runnable) virtual app. When it gets the arguments it must decide either to hand them off to a currently running instance of our main virtual app or spawn a new instance of the main app with the command line arguments set (we achieve this using *JWSystem.forkVirtualApp(...)*).

We see mentioned on the URL Handling FAQ page from JWrapper [here](http://www.jwrapper.com/guide-url-handling.html) that only MacOS is able to register an event handler to respond to URL openings and that there is a suggestion for windows...

> On Windows this isn't possible directly since Windows doesn't support it however a dedicated URL-handling virtual app which then communicated the URLs to your main app would achieve the same result.

My question is; how exactly do we get a hold of our running main virtual app and how do we pass it some arguments? Is there a particular approach that we should use?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do some of this with JWrapper's IPC (Inter-Process Communication) capabilities. Here is an old article talking about some of this: http://www.jwrapper.com/blog/aes-encrypted-multiplexed-inter-process-communication-for-java

Here is is a javadoc for the class that covers IPC in JWrapper: http://simple-help.com/media/static/jwrapper/jwutils/JWSockIPC.html

You could also coordinate by watching a particular file as a means of communicating between your virtual apps.